# Powershell Find all empty folders and subfolders in a given Folder name

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I´m trying to get a
a) list of all empty folders and subfolders if the folder is named "Archiv"
b) I´d like to delete all those empty folders. My current approch doesn´t check the subfolders.

It would be also great if the results would be exportet in a .csv =)

```
$TopDir = 'C:\Users\User\Test'

$DirToFind = 'Archiv'>$EmptyDirList = @(
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Directory -Recurse |
        Where-Object {
            #[System.IO.Directory]::GetFileSystemEntries($_.FullName).Count -eq 0
            $_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 0 -and
            $_.Name -match $DirToFind
            }
        ).FullName

$EmptyDirList
```

Any ideas how to adjust the code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order in which Get-ChildItem lists the items so you can remove using the deepest nested empty folder first.

```
$LogFile = 'C:\Users\User\RemovedEmptyFolders.log'
$TopDir  = 'C:\Users\User\Test'

# first get a list of all folders below the $TopDir directory that are named 'Archiv' (FullNames only)
$archiveDirs = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Filter 'Archiv' -Recurse -Directory -Force).FullName | 
                # sort on the FullName.Length property in Descending order to get 'deepest-nesting-first' 
                Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending 

# next, remove all empty subfolders in each of the $archiveDirs
$removed = foreach ($dir in $archiveDirs) {
    (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Directory -Force) |
    # sort on the FullName.Length property in Descending order to get 'deepest-nesting-first' 
    Sort-Object @{Expression = {$_.FullName.Length}} -Descending | 
    ForEach-Object {
       # if this folder is empty, remove it and output its FullName for the log
       if (@($_.GetFileSystemInfos()).Count -eq 0) { 
           $_.FullName
           Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Force
       }
    }
    # next remove the 'Archiv' folder that is now possibly empty too
    if (@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Force).Count -eq 0) {
        # output this folders fullname and delete
        $dir
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $dir -Force
    }
}

$removed | Set-Content -Path $LogFile -PassThru  # write your log file. -PassThru also writes the output on screen
```

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be a further problem:
PowerShell error: get-ChildItem: "a part of the path "path-name" couldn´t be found therefore the method get-ChildItem is not working..

Comment: @Peppino Try `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath`

Comment: @Peppino Sorry, just noticed the filter should be `Archiv`, not `Archive`

Comment: I changed both cases but I still get the same error

Comment: @Peppino I edited the code. If you still get that error, it could be that some paths exceed the 260 character path limit.. Make sure your windows [accepts long paths](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/enable-long-file-name-support-windows-10)

Comment: the edited code does not delete the folder which is named "Archiv". It checks if the subforders under this folder are empty and deletes if so (this works fine). Bute it also should delete the Folder "Archiv" if there are no files or a subfolder with a file in it

Comment: @Peppino Ah, I misread the question and thought you wanted to keep them. I have now added code to also remove the `Archiv` folders as well if they have become empty

Comment: Last question: is it possible to change the code therefore that the Folderstructre isn´t in the explorer but sharepoint365?

Comment: @Peppino SharePoint is a whole different thing then a folder structure on disk, but anyway.. SharePoint is not my expertise I'm afraid..

Comment: I´m Sry but there is still smth. which isn´t working the way I though it will.
Folder structure as followed:

[....]/Archiv/Folder A/Folder B/Folder C,D,E,F,G,H

Folder B ist just a Folder without any documents, it´s just leading to Folder C-H
Let´s assume folder C,D,E and H have no documents. At the moment the won´t be deleted and I don´t unterstand why..
It´s not caused by the length of the path

Comment: @Peppino Sometimes folders contain hidden and/or system files that normally do not show up in File Explorer like `thumbs.db` or `desktop.ini`. Because I'm using `-Force` in `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Force`, these files you do not see **ARE** counted, therefore these folders aren't empty. You can check what is inside them by temporarily [let Explorer show them](https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/Article/41890).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure a CSV is needed, I think a simple text file will suffice as it's just a list.
Anyway, here's (although not the most elegant) a solution which will also delete "nested empty directories". Meaning if a directory only contains empty directorIS, it will also get deleted

```
$TopDir = "C:\Test" #Top level directory to scan
$EmptyDirListReport = "C:\EmptyDirList.txt" #Text file location to store a file with the list of deleted directorues
if (Test-Path -Path $EmptyDirListReport -PathType Leaf)
{
    Remove-Item -Path $EmptyDirListReport -Force
}
$EmptyDirList = ""
Do
{
    $EmptyDirList = Get-ChildItem -Path $TopDir -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.PSIsContainer } | Where-Object -FilterScript { ((Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName).Count -eq 0) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    if ($EmptyDirList)
    {
        $EmptyDirList | Out-File -FilePath $EmptyDirListReport -Append
        $EmptyDirList | Remove-Item -Force
    }
} while ($EmptyDirList)
```

Comment: Seems perfect that the nested empty directories will be deleted but there is there a filter for the folder name "Archiv"?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, should works with nested too.

```
$result=(Get-ChildItem -Filter "Archiv" -Recurse -Directory  $topdir | Sort-Object @{Expression = {$_.FullName.Length}} -Descending | ForEach-Object {
     if ((Get-ChildItem -Attributes d,h,a $_.fullname).count -eq 0){
         $_
         rmdir $_.FullName
      } 
})
$result | select Fullname |ConvertTo-Csv |Out-File $Logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner:

```
> Get-ChildItem -Recurse dir -filter Archiv | 
    Where-Object {($_ | Get-ChildItem).count -eq 0} | 
      Remove-Item
```

Although, for some reason, if you have nested Archiv files like `Archiv/Archiv`, you need to run the line several times.