# Delete empty folders - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I´m using this code (provided from [Powershell Find all empty folders and subfolders in a given Folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708523/powershell-find-all-empty-folders-and-subfolders-in-a-given-folder-name)) but it isn´t working the way it should.

I want to delete all subfolders which are nested under a Folder named Archiv. The actual code isn´t able to delete subfolders which are nested as the following example shows it.

Folder structure as followed: [....]/Archiv/Folder A/Folder B/Folder C,D,E,F,G,H Folder B ist just a Folder without any documents, it´s just leading to Folder C-H Let´s assume folder C,D,E and H have no documents. At the moment the won´t be deleted and I don´t unterstand why.. It´s not caused by the length of the path

```
$LogFile = 'C:\Users\User\RemovedEmptyFolders.log'
$TopDir  = 'C:\Users\User\Test'

# first get a list of all folders below the $TopDir directory that are named 'Archiv' (FullNames only)
$archiveDirs = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Filter 'Archiv' -Recurse -Directory -Force).FullName | 
                # sort on the FullName.Length property in Descending order to get 'deepest-nesting-first' 
                Sort-Object -Property Length -Descending 

# next, remove all empty subfolders in each of the $archiveDirs
$removed = foreach ($dir in $archiveDirs) {
    (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Directory -Force) |
    # sort on the FullName.Length property in Descending order to get 'deepest-nesting-first' 
    Sort-Object @{Expression = {$_.FullName.Length}} -Descending | 
    ForEach-Object {
       # if this folder is empty, remove it and output its FullName for the log
       if (@($_.GetFileSystemInfos()).Count -eq 0) { 
           $_.FullName
           Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Force
       }
    }
    # next remove the 'Archiv' folder that is now possibly empty too
    if (@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Force).Count -eq 0) {
        # output this folders fullname and delete
        $dir
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $dir -Force
    }
}

$removed | Set-Content -Path $LogFile -PassThru  # write your log file. -PassThru also writes the output on screen
```

Comment: What error are you getting when deleting those directories?

Comment: As I [commented in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708523/powershell-find-all-empty-folders-and-subfolders-in-a-given-folder-name#comment121519421_68709655), these folders may contain hidden or system files you do not see in Explorer. They are not empty then, it just _seems_ they are

Comment: @Theo, wouldn't the `-Force` switch expose those hidden files?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes, but then the code doesn't reveal the contents of the directories. If the OP doesn't care about losing them, he could remove the `-Force` switch from all `Get-ChildItem` lines. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure if `.GetFileSystemInfos()` counts these hidden or system files (can't test right now).. If so, the not-really-empty subfolders still wouldn't be removed and that part needs to be replaced by `@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName).Count -eq 0)` too.

Comment: @ theo: I checked some paths if they exibit hidden or system files but they didn´t. That´s why I´m so confused

Comment: The error which occured in the passthru says:
Get-ChildItem: A part of the path (then the path in named) couldn´t be found. Followed by:

+ ... hiveDirs = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Filter 'Archiv' -Recu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\User...1001-326-108823:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand